# How to get the index of each character of a string from the end

Tags: java, string, indexof

I want to access the index of  character of a string from end using a loop but when i provide the last character of the string same as any character before the last character, then it is returning the index of the character which comes first in the string.

here i have taken String str="2021+58-035/235" i want that the method checkStringFromLast() should return the index of "/" but it is returning the index of "+"

if the last character in the string is different from all the characters in the string then it returns the correct value

suppose if i will change the value of 5 with any other character like 2021+58-035/239 then it returns the index of "/"

```
public class ForCalculator {
    public int checkStringFromLast(String sc){
        int i=sc.indexOf(sc.charAt(sc.length()-1));
        while(i>=0){
            if(sc.charAt(i)=='x'||sc.charAt(i)=='+'||sc.charAt(i)=='-'||sc.charAt(i)=='/'){
                System.out.println("returning "+i);
                return i;
            }
            i--;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ForCalculator obj = new ForCalculator();
        String str = "92021+58-035/235";
        System.out.println(obj.checkStringFromLast(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `indexOf` method will return the first instance of the character. It can't differentiate between two different 5's, for example. They are the same character. Wouldn't your code work if you just did `int i = sc.length() - 1;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i=sc.indexOf(sc.charAt(sc.length()-1));
```

should probably be

```
int i=sc.lastIndexOf(sc.charAt(sc.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

since i was trying to find the index of the last character of a string and so it can be found using `sc.length()-1`

```
int i= sc.length()-1;
```

actually `sc.length()-1` will give the index of the last character in the string sc